# Vim and GVim: leader key not working

Tags: vim

I have some plugins installed, including NERDCommenter and NERDTree.  I can't get the leader key to work right for them, though.  These are the default configs when I type `:map`

```
v  \c<Space>     <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
n  \c<Space>     <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
v  \cc           <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
n  \cc           <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
```

`\c<space>` just works like hitting `c<space>`.  I've tried remapping the leader key with the following in my `.vimrc` in my home directory:

```
let mapleader = ","
```

This is reflected when I restart vim and type `:map`

```
v  ,c<Space>     <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
n  ,c<Space>     <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
v  ,cc           <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
n  ,cc           <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
```

But still, `,c<space>` just behaves like I'm hitting `c<space>`.  What's going on and how do I fix this?

**Edit**: tested this in VIM as well with the same behavior.

Comment: You are supposed to hit these keys very quickly. What is the output of `set updatetime?`? That's the number of milliseconds you have.

Comment: `updatetime=4000`.  This is the 4 second default.  I'm not hitting them too slow.

Comment: @balki: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: You cannot even begin how thankful I am for this thread. 10.000 times THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The mappings seem funny, I'd expect

```
v  <Leader>c<Space>     <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
n  <Leader>c<Space>     <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle
v  <Leader>cc           <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
n  <Leader>cc           <Plug>NERDCommenterComment
```

for them to work. I suspect you are setting the mapleader *after* the plugins get loaded

Comment: `<Leader>` and `<LocalLeader>` are expanded when `map`/`noremap` is called. If OP changed mapleader after the mappings are set, the change wouldn't be reflected in them.

Comment: I'm using `let mapleader = ","` in my `~/.vimrc`.  Based on what I've read, .vimrc is loaded before any plugins, and those plugins define the mappings (but I'm not entirely sure about that)

Comment: @EricHu: plugins are loaded during vimrc, IIRC. Try moving the `mapleader` setting to the top? See also the [**Note** over here at vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapleader)

Comment: @sehe *groan* yeah, that was it.  Thanks!

Comment: @EricHu: let's say I'm glad you _found_ it!

Comment: moving `let mapleader = ","` to the top of `~/.vimrc` worked for me, thank you !

Answer (score 19):

Define `mapleader` and `maplocalleader` keys before any of the plugins are loaded.

Right on top of your .vimrc!

Answer (score 14):

You may have set your timeout to zero. In that case, vim won't wait for the key after the mapleader.

```
:set timeout timeoutlen=0 ttimeoutlen=0
```

Answer (score 1):

This will likely not be the answer for most but may help a small few...

I am running a debian distro (PureOS in my case, though the specific flavor may not totally matter) and the default `\` leader key is mapped to `<` out of the box.

For me, remapping the key code was the fix:

`sudo setkeycodes 56 43`