# Vim: Leader not working

Tags: vim, leader

When trying to use `vim-latexsuite`'s mappings, the ones using `Leader` are not working:

```
:nmap
----------------------------------------
n  <Leader>rf   @<Plug>Tex_RefreshFolds
n  <Leader>ls   @<Plug>Tex_ForwardSearch
n  <Leader>lv   @<Plug>Tex_View
n  <Leader>ll   @<Plug>Tex_Compile
```

All other mappings by this plugin are working, so the plugin is being loaded correctly. Without `mapleader` being set, `Leader` should default to `\` (Backslash).

When typing `\ll` in command mode, the cursor gets moved 2 characters to the right, as it's supposed to by just typing `ll`. So the Backslash seems to be ignored. Vim does not beep or display any errors and the `ll` follows earlier than 1000ms, which is my `timeoutlen`.

I have also tried the following settings in both `.vimrc` and `/etc/vimrc` (Though I assume only `mapleader` needs to be set here):

```
let mapleader = ","
let maplocalleader = ","
```

After this, Vim behaves the same way: No beep, no error and after typing `,ll` the cursor moves 2 characters to the right.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What do you get when you type `:echo mapleader`? :verbose nmap \?

Comment: :echo mapleader -> `,` and :verbose nmap \ (or ,) -> `No mapping found`

Comment: Here, `:nmap` and `:nmap <leader>` don't return `n <Leader>b SomeCommand` but `n ,b SomeCommand`. Note that `<leader>` is expanded to its value. It looks to my untrained eyes as if the value of mapleader would be set to the string `<Leader>`, which seems quite weird.

Comment: This may not be the case here but it's a useful tidbit nonetheless.. If mapleader is changed after a plugin is already loaded the new mapleader will not be a part of the mappings for that plugin.  Another quirk with mapleader.

Comment: Manually reinstalling the plugin didn't change anything. Any more ideas?

Comment: If you edit the plugins code and make a mapping next to the other ones that just echo's "test", does it work?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `:nnoremap <Leader>d dd` I added this to my .vimrc and `:nmap` returns `n  <Leader>d   * dd`. When i type ",d", only one "d" is being shown in the bottom right corner. So it doesn't work either. 

As i said in the Question, the other mappings of the plugin are working.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189055/vim-and-gvim-leader-key-not-working

Comment: Yes, and my `let mapleader = ","` is at the top of my .vimrc. But even without that working, the Leader should default to \, which doesn't work either (Both \ and , seem to be ignored by Vim).

Answer (score 11):

If you've shortened `timeoutlen`, you won't be able to type quickly enough. If you look at `:help 'ttimeoutlen'`, you'll see it suggests:

```
:set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to clear a content of ~/.viminfo file and if you are using a session plugin -- clear a session data in generated file. Then restart Vim. It helps me sometimes when I experiment with different settings, mappings etc.

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same problem as the original post, and when I deleted the .viminfo and reloaded, the remapped leader key worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling Vim, removing all plugin and config files and reinstalling it, the Leader works just fine. Unfortunately, i don't know what exactly caused Vim to ignore the Leader.

Comment: In my case, I had some conflicting "let mapleader" leader changes in a couple ~/.vim/ftplugin/tex_*.vim that were executing in the wrong order. Having them execute in the right order solved it for me without a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mapping like this in your `.vimrc`,

```
nmap <Leader>rf @<Plug>Tex_RefreshFolds
```

then the output of `nmap` (without arguments) should be this:

```
n  \rf   @<Plug>Tex_RefreshFolds
```

In other words, "<Leader>" should be expanded to "\".
Since this is not the case for you, something is going wrong with your mapping. This could be caused by having "<" in your cpoptions. Try `set cpoptions?` to check.