# Simple vim keymapping not working

Tags: vim

When I use `map qq :wq` in my .vimrc, I see "recording" in the status bar rather than seeing vim save and close the file. How can I achieve this mapping?

Comment: Note: I suspect you want to do `map qq :wq<Enter>` instead, as this will actually run the command.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help.

Comment: Your command as given works on my box (Vim 7.4.131), so I'm not sure what's wrong.  Is there a reason you aren't using ZZ?

Comment: I didn't know about that command, thanks. Is there a similar command for save-without-exit?

Comment: @RosePerrone are you sure that your vimrc is being loaded?

Comment: @RosePerrone save and exit: `ZZ`, exit without save: `ZQ`, did you try open your vim, and type your mapping command in vim? by `:map ....`?

Comment: @Kent The command didn't work when I ran the map command in vim. I want to create a shortcut for save without exit, not exit without save.

Comment: @RosePerrone the `:map...` line should work anyway, there must be some information you forgot telling here. and it is not very clear, what does `it didn't work` mean. can your open your vim, and test this two lines, 1) `:map qq :wq<cr>` then press Enter, after that, 2) `:map qq` report the output pls. To save the current buffer (don't exit): `:w`

Comment: Like others have said above, there's some level of miscommunication here. You need to type out all of `map qq :wq<Enter>` instead of pressing Enter after `:wq` in the `.vimrc`. It's also advisable to use `nnoremap` instead of `map` in this case. Personally I map `nnoremap <leader>w :w<cr>` to satisfy my neurotic saving needs. I'm trying to wean myself off from using it so much though.

Comment: @Kent the output is `   qq            :wq<CR>`, but still when I hit `qq`, I see `recording`.

Comment: `:wq` is "save and exit" and `qq` is quite possibly one of the most useful Vim shortcut, I'm not sure you *want* to shadow it. If you want "save without exit" you want `:w`. Anyway, `:map qq :wq<CR>` works perfectly.

Comment: Can you open Vim without your vimrc (`vim -u NONE`), apply just that mapping manually, and see if it works? [I agree with romainl, though -- I use `qq` very frequently to record a one-off macro. Very handy.]

Comment: @pandubear When I do that, I type in qq, and `:wq<Enter>` appears in the command bar, and typing characters appends to that message, but the action doesn't execute. The file is not saved and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rose, I believe your mapping doesn't work because `qq` command records typed characters into `q` register and it can't be remapped. Here is the excerpt from the help:

```
q{0-9a-zA-Z"}  Record typed characters into register {0-9a-zA-Z"}
               (uppercase to append).  The 'q' command is disabled
               while executing a register, and it doesn't work inside
               a mapping and |:normal|.  {Vi: no recording}
```

Actually, I would recommend you to use other mappings instead. Here is what you can use, for example:

1) `ZZ` for writing current file, if modified, and quit. Also `ZQ` can be used to quit without checking for changes.

2) The following mapping:

```
noremap <silent> <Leader>x :x<CR>
```

here is what help says about `:x` command:

```
:[range]x[it][!] [++opt] [file]
            Like ":wq", but write only when changes have been
            made.
            When 'hidden' is set and there are more windows, the
            current buffer becomes hidden, after writing the file.
```

Additionally, probably you will find these mappings helpful if you need to have separate mappings for `:w` and `:q!`commands:

```
noremap <silent> <Leader>w :w<CR>
noremap <silent> <Leader>q :q!<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer, but it looks like I need to uninstall and reinstall plugins to get vim to properly recognize my keybindings again, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560294/vim-leader-not-working.

Comment: Probably, you don't need to reinstall plugins. Try just clear the content of ~/.viminfo file and if you're using a session plugin - clear the content of a created session file too. Then you need to restart Vim.

Comment: No luck. Vim refuses to recognize my mapleader, whether it's the default `\` or I include `let mapleader = ","`. Either way, when I hit the key in command mode, the "you made an error with your keyboard" alarm goes off and nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm, it's pretty strange. What `:echo mapleader` command prints for you? Does it print your mapleader key? Also, you can try to run Vim without plugins `vim --noplugin`. If your mapleader works in that mode, try to disable all your plugins and enable them one by one. So you will find a plugin that caused the problem.

Comment: Even when I run `vim` with `vim --noplugin`, when I execute `:echo mapleader`, I see: `E121: Undefined variable: mapleader`, and on a secod line: `E15: Invalid expression: mapleader`.

Comment: Well, I think it's time to reinstall Vim and all plugins.